# How to pass a database variable in to a controller function

Tags: matlab, codeigniter

I have to take the  last inserted image name from the database and I need to  pass it to a controller function.

Model

```
function getimage()
  {

    $maxid = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(id) AS `maxid` FROM `brain`')->row()->maxid;
    $this->db->select("image");
    $this->db->from('brain');
    $this->db->where('id =', $maxid);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
  }
```

Controller

```
public function matlabcall() {


        $command = "matlab -sd " . getcwd() . " -r MedianFiltering_denoising('" . IMAGENAME . "')";
        exec($command);


    }
```

I need to replace the image name,in the place of **'IMAGENAME'.**

sql table

```
id  image 

1   images/pic1.png
2   images/pic2.png
```

here 'images' refers the folder.I need to remove the folder name and get the image name separately and need to pass it the controller function.
please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically a controller will use a model to get data and then act on the model's return. In this case, the model's return is sent to `matlabcall()` which is simply another function of the controller.

You don't show the controller's definition so I've made one up.

**Controller file:**

```
class Brain_controller extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('brain_images');
  }

  public function newest_brain_image()
  {
    $image = $this->brain_images->get_image();
    $this->matlabcall($image);
  }

  public function matlabcall($image_name)
  {
    $cwd = getcwd();
    $command = "matlab -sd $cwd -r MedianFiltering_denoising('$image_name')";
    exec($command);
  }

}
```

There is no point in using Query Builder syntax to create what is a really simple query. This code will be much more efficient, easier to read, and probably measurably faster.

**Model file:**

```
class Brain_images extends CI_Model
{
  function get_image()
  {
    $sql = "select image from brain where id = (select MAX(id) from brain)";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->row()->image;
  }

}
```

Hope I have correctly understood your need and that this helps.